Is it possible to use Vuforia to get the original image from the web camera of the device? (Unity)
Is it possible to use Vuforia to get the original image from the web camera of the device in Unity? At the moment it is possible to get a texture from CameraDevice, but it is already 640*360, although the original resolution of the camera is FullHD.
I've tried getting the image through CameraDevice, but it returns a thumbnail image. Unfortunately I didn't find a similar question here and in the Vuforia documentation too.
